# Command file: Expect+Title. How can I do this?

Tags: bash, command, title, expect

How can I do a command file (macOS) or similar (GNU/Linux) with `expect` and a `title`?

Now I use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn rm -rf /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts

spawn ssh username@IP
expect "?"
send "yes\r"
expect "assword:"
send "thepassword\r"
expect "thenamemachine:~#"
send "bash <(curl -s aFile.sh)\r"
interact
```

But how can I add this

```
title='My first title'
echo -n -e "\033]0;$title\007"
```

Because of this doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

title='My first title'
echo -n -e "\033]0;$title\007"

set timeout -1

spawn rm -rf /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts

spawn ssh username@IP
expect "?"
send "yes\r"
expect "assword:"
send "thepassword\r"
expect "thenamemachine:~#"
send "bash <(curl -s aFile.sh)\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) syntax in an expect script, not shell. You want:

```
set title "My first title"
send_user "\033]0;$title\007"
```

Also, you don't need to have any interaction with `rm -rf`, so use `exec` instead of `spawn`:

```
exec rm -rf /path/to/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And really thanks for the **exec** tip too!